# Problem to run Nativescript app on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, nativescript

after updating my NS app to latest version.. I am now suffering to run it on my iOS device..app simply does not open even though its installed. I was trying to run from xcode and got this msg on log :

**Class TKDataSource is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/CryptoTokenKit.framework/CryptoTokenKit (0x1fdff00d8) and /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A97BDBFB-56E2-4303-A817-F582CEF25550/MYDOC.app/Frameworks/TNSListView.framework/TNSListView (0x104966e70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.**

**ns run ios** shows this error :

**unable to apply changes on device: 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E. Error is: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/timmrichter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E/data/Applications'.**

Any Idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an Applications folder to the path /Users/timmrichter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E/data.

Comment: I tried also but on log I get this : **Successfully installed on device with identifier '7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E'.
Successfully transferred all files on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E.
Restarting application on device 7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E...
CONSOLE INFO: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
NativeScript discarding uncaught JS exception!**

Answer (score 0):

I hit that problem, too.  I was able to bypass it by opening the emulator via xcode first, and then entering `tns run ios --emulator`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to run with xcode and build was sucess but app does not open. on log I get this : **Runtime initialization took 123ms
2020-10-05 10:41:47.274939+0200 MYDOC[4883:68182] CONSOLE INFO: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
2020-10-05 10:41:47.300866+0200 MYDOC[4883:68182] NativeScript discarding uncaught JS exception!**

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was making the directory that's trying to be scanned. So in your case running the command

" mkdir /Users/timmrichter/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7BE6C620-A73C-42DF-81AD-65A0083CB13E/data/Applications "

Should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I have some plugins like i18n which seems not supported on NS latest version. At the end I have downgraded to version 6.5.3 and it's now working on iOS 14.